# Select max key from joined keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I have a table that contains keys that have been changed to a different key. These are laid out like this:

```
origkey newkey
1        2
2        3
4        5
6        7
7        8
8        9
9        10
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a query that takes the origkey and finds the max newkey for each one. In the example above, the results would look like:

```
origkey maxkey
1        3
4        5
6        10
```

If I knew the maximum amount of times that the key could have been changed, I would just add that amount of self joins and get it from there. Unfortunately, I don't know how many times it could have changed in the past. Is there a way to keep self joining until it finds a null? The following query will return the changed keys into new columns, but I think I'm going down the wrong road here since this will get the 1 -> 3 change, but not the 6 -> 10 change.

```
select a.origkey
,a.newkey
,b.newkey newkey1
,c.newkey newkey2 
from changedkeys a
Left Outer Join changedkeys b on a.newkey=b.origkey
Left Outer Join changedkeys c on b.newkey=c.origkey
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't cache the Newest value somewhere? And/Or is this table too big to realistically be able to just write a function to do it?

Comment: Going forward, we will be storing the latest value to make this easier, but that will always make it one degree of separation and easy to account for. Now that I'm doing history, I'll only need to do this once. Functions may be the answer I'm looking for, but I don't have any experience with them.

Comment: How are you deciding that the origkey 1 maps to newkey of 3?

Comment: The origkey is mapped to a newkey. In the same table, that same newkey is then in the origkey column with a different newkey. (I hope I explained that right..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way.  It is called a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select origkey, newkey, 1 as lev
      from table1
      union all
      select cte.origkey, t1.newkey, lev + 1
      from cte join
           table1 t1
           on cte.newkey = t1.origkey
    )
select origkey, newkey as newestkey
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by origkey order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this assumes that there are no cycles in the key definitions, as in the example in your question.  If this is a possibility, the recursive CTE can be modified to handle this.

EDIT:

If you have potential cycles in the data, then try this:

```
with cte as (
      select origkey, newkey, 1 as lev, ',' + cast(newkey as varchar(8000)) + ',' as keys
      from table1
      union all
      select cte.origkey, t1.newkey, cte.lev + 1, keys + cast(t1.newkey as varchar(8000)) + ','
      from cte join
           table1 t1
           on cte.newkey = t1.origkey
      where ',' + t1.keys + ',' not like '%,' + cast(t1.newkey as varchar(8000)) + '%,'
    )
select origkey, newkey as newestkey
from (select cte.*, row_number() over (partition by origkey order by lev desc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the t.* just be *? Also, how does the CTE know when to stop? I only say that because I get a max recursion error when I changed that.

Comment: I think you are correct, it should be `*`, or `cte.*`.  As for recursive CTEs, the CTE will stop when the previous loop doesn't return any rows.  [Further reading](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I guess I still don't know what's wrong since I get max recursion errors using the recursive CTE, and setting the OPTION (MAXRECUSION 0) just hangs for a bit. Enough for my DBA to ask me what I'm doing and if I could stop. heh

Comment: Thank you Gordon! That worked so far after I made a couple slight changes, which I think are typos. `t1.keys` should just be `keys`, `lev + 1` should be `cte.lev + 1` and the second `cast(newkey...` should be `cast(t1.newkey...)`. I think I have the logic right on that last one, it could be `cast(cte.newkey..)`. Either way, I'm validating it does what I want it to do completely, but this is amazing! Thanks again!